# Queries, Forms stop working with new table

Tags: ms-access

I originally had a table called 'DATA' that I used in multiple queries which was from a linked excel document. This 'DATA' table's information was outdated, so I deleted the old table 'DATA' and re-linked a new 'DATA' to a new excel sheet named 'DATA' with new information.

None of my queries are using this new table, only the old table. I've tried refreshing all, rebuilding the queries - nothing seems to work.

Is there some kind of cached memory of the operations that ms access keeps that I need to clear? If not, why aren't any of my queries using the new table?
Thanks!

Comment: What data are you seeing in the table link? No, there is no 'cache'. I suspect you have not really linked to a 'new' file. Should be able to copy over the old file and as long as the structure is the same, the link will still work but now display new data.

Comment: " nothing seems to work." -- what does that mean??